# gradle publish custom pom

Tags: maven, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have written a gradle task which writes a custom pom to "build/libs/pom.xml"

I want to publish above custom pom.xml , so I defined :

```
def pomXml = artifacts.add('archives', file("$buildDir/libs/pom.xml")) {
    builtBy('writePoms')   // writePoms is my custom task to create custom pom.xml
}

publishing {
  publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {

        artifact pomXml
        artifactId "myartifact"
        groupId 'com.xyz'
        version project.version
    }
 }

repositories {
    // Task for manually publishing the maven image. When CI works, setup CI_TOKEN auth.
    maven {
        url <url>
        name "GitLab"
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
            name = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN") ? "Job-Token" : "Private-Token"
            value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN") ? System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN") : gitLabPrivateToken
        }
        authentication {
            header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradlew publish` it publishes pom from "build/publications/maven/pom-default.xml" instead of "build/libs/pom.xml"

Can someone help how can I achieve it?

Comment: what is your main artifact for which you are customising the POM ? jar or zip something like that.

Comment: Main artifact is a fat jar, which is published without issues

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (aggregate build of multiple external repositories with their own build systems and then publishing the results of those builds to a local artifactory).

I was able to effectively replace the generated POM for the "artifacts" publication with the content of an external POM via `withXml`:

```
pluginManager.withPlugin("maven-publish") {
    extensions.configure(PublishingExtension::class.java) {
        publications.register<MavenPublication>("artifacts") {
            groupId = "com.example"
            artifactId = "external"
            version = "1.0.0"

            artifact("external.jar")
            pom.withXml {
                asNode().setValue(XmlParser().parse("some/external/pom.xml").value())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This leaves the `<xml ...>` and `<project ...>` nodes intact (acceptable for my case).